# ruby on rails descending loop increments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

How do I descent from 5 to 1 instead of going from 1 to 5? I have this...

```
<div class="field-container rating">
  <% (5..1).each do |i| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :rating, i, :id => "star#{i}" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

`(1..5)` goes from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. What is the correct way of going 5, 4, 3, 2, 1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do [downto](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-downto)

```
<div class="field-container rating">
  <% 5.downto(1) do |i| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :rating, i, :id => "star#{i}" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah Ruby...this is way better than the Pythonesque suggestion I was about to make (setting a variable, decrementing it in a `while` loop).

Comment: very simple and easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_a.reverse`

```
for i in (1..5).to_a.reverse
   puts i
end
```